# An MC question involing cosine law

Tags: trigonometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles, solid-geometry

I saw this question in an DSE exam.

[image]

I can solve it via:-

Method #1 (Numerical method)

(1.1) Letting PQ = 1; (1.2) Turn all lines into numerical data (eg. $QR= \dfrac {1}{ \tan 47^0} = 0.932515$); (1.3) Apply cosine law to get he required.

Method#1.1 (Testing each options)

(1) From method #1, I got RS = 1.462918; RP = … and PS = …. (2) Use the cosine formula program to test each option.

This approach is not recommended because it only requires techniques in answering mc question and has no value in edutcation. *** the following comment is deleted ***

Method #2 (applying trigometric identities)

Essentially, this is the same as method #1 except I leave the value of each line un-simpliied (eg. $QR= \dfrac {1}{ \tan 47^0}$) so that some cancellations can be done via trigonometric identities, and special angles.

All the methods require quite a bit of computations/simplifications and I don’t think the question can be solved within 1.5 minutes for an MC question.

So is the question fair? Or is there a tricky way (like considering the volume of the tetrahefron) that can give an answer quicker?

Comment: What complementary angles? Using cosine law twice seems to be the most straightforward method, considering most students have both versions programmed in their calculators. There should also be a suggested solution at the back of the booklet if it is from DSE.

Comment: @player3236 My bad for the complementary angle part. Will edit it. For the MC's, the booklet gives the correct options only with comment (if that is necessary).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\measuredangle RPS=\alpha$.

Thus, by the law of cosines we have
$$PS^2+PR^2-2PS\cdot PR\cos\alpha=SQ^2+RQ^2+SQ\cdot RQ$$ or
$$2PS\cdot PR\cos\alpha=PQ^2+PQ^2-SQ\cdot RQ$$ or
$$\cos\alpha=\frac{PQ^2}{PS\cdot PR}-\frac{SQ\cdot RQ}{2PS\cdot PR}$$ or
$$\cos\alpha=\sin53^{\circ}\sin47^{\circ}-\frac{1}{2}\cos53^{\circ}\cos47^{\circ},$$ which gives
$$\alpha=\arccos\left(\sin53^{\circ}\sin47^{\circ}-\frac{1}{2}\cos53^{\circ}\cos47^{\circ}\right)\approx68^{\circ}.$$

Comment: Applying compound angle formula to your last equality, I get the following equivalent:
$\alpha = \arccos \left( \dfrac{-3 \cos (53^{\circ}+ 47^{\circ}) + \cos (53^{\circ} -  47^{\circ})}{4}\right)$. Will there be any geometrical meaning we can deduce?

Comment: @Mick Maybe it's possible. I don't see something interesting.